# Can I play Dead Island over a LAN?

Tags: dead-island

Tomorrow I'm going to go to visit my friend, I will bring my laptop.
He has Dead Island, and If there is any way we can play on LAN, I will also buy it.

Does it have LAN?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can, in fact you can specifically set it (in options) to allow only LAN, or both (I think it's both, it might just be internet), or neither. Just go into:

> Options > Online > Gametype - Co-operative > Game Visibility - LAN